# PHP If Else Not working like i thought it would

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok i am very stuck here and i am might be looking at this completely wrong (still kind of a newbie) or super close just missing something small i cant tell.

At the bottom here you will find my code with a If ElseIf Else statement. That i just cant get to do what i want. so i am hoping someone can help guide me in the right direction.

On the If it checks to make sure that the promocode that was entered is in the database and that part works.

on the elseif i want it to look through the database and find the promocode and confirm that there isnt an email address associated with that promocode. The way that it is below with the IS NOT NULL in the query works for when there is an email address in that promocode but when there isnt anything for that promocode it is still saying that there is and gives the submit data of today but i can assure that there isnt anything in the database.

This is where my problem lies am i doing this completely wrong is there a better way to accomplish what i am trying to do here? Or have i just overlooked something small?

```
        $promosql = "SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE (promoCode = '$varPromo')";
        $promoraw = $mysqli->query($promosql);

        $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE (promoCode = '$varPromo' AND email IS NOT NULL)";
        $duperaw = $mysqli->query($dupesql);

        if($promoraw->num_rows <> 1) {
            //echo ("$varName already exists in $varAddress \n");
            $promo .= "$varPromo is not a valid promocode \n";
        } 
        elseif($duperaw->num_rows > 0) {
            //echo ("$varName already exists in $varAddress \n");
            $dupe .= "$varPromo has already been used on $varDate \n";
        } 
        else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO formdata (promoCode, name, email, address, city, state, zip, submitDate) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($varPromo) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varName) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varEmail) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varAddress) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varCity) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varState) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varZip) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varDate) . ")";
        $mysqli->query($sql);

        header("location: index.php?success=1");
        exit();
        }
```

Comment: Use parameterised queries instead of string concatenation.

Comment: The line `if($promoraw->num_rows <> 1)` should be `if($promoraw->num_rows != 1)`.

The line `elseif($duperaw->num_rows > 0)` should be `else if($duperaw->num_rows > 0)`.

Comment: @DissidentRage actually, elseif is correct.

Comment: What is that `PrepSQL` funtion doing there if you use mysqli? Why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: @markus Learning something new every day.

Comment: @Travis you should also do error checking as well to make sure that your queries are actually working before issuing more queries and performing more logic with them.

Comment: Why perform two `SELECT` queries? All the information comes back on the first one. You can check it directly.

Comment: @MikeW If i knew how to do that i would but clearly i only know enough to be dangerous.

Comment: @DissidentRage I am not sure how to check the queries but i run it through PHPMYADMIN it seems to work as it is supposed to

Comment: You only need to run the first query because you already get back whether or not the e-mail is null. Mike is saying to do a check for !is_null at the PHP level instead so that you aren't hitting up the database multiple times and causing latency. It's a good catch. Also IIRC the act of assigning a query result to a variable will in itself return false if the query fails.

Comment: Could `email` be an empty string instead of `NULL`?

Comment: @Barmar it could be... how can i tell the difference to show my knowledge i thought that empty meant null

Comment: `SELECT email IS NULL FROM formdata WHERE promoCode = 'whatever'`

Comment: `NULL` is a special value that means the column isn't set at all. It's different from the empty string, and has very special properties. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: With this    SELECT email IS NULL FROM formdata WHERE promoCode = 'whatever' it still posts to the DB with or without email being in the record

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT email IS NULL or email = '' has_email FROM formdata WHERE promoCode = '$varPromo'
```

Then your PHP can do:

```
if ($promoraw->nul_rows == 0) {
    // Not a valid promo code
} else {
    $row = $promoraw->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row['has_email']) {
        // Promo code has been used
    } else {
        // Insert into table
    }
}
```